# How to scroll to top of the page using appium?

Tags: scroll, appium

I am new on Appium.

I am testing hybrid android app using Appium. I want to scroll to top of page and then click on one link. Could anyone please tell me how to scroll to page bottom.

Many thanks

Comment: hybrid means you have implemented it on webview I am right ?

Comment: yes @jiteshmohite